# What's the difference between oracle server and client database

Tags: oracle

Can any one tell me what's the difference between oracle server and client database??
And do I choose which one to install during the installation process??
What about Oracle 10g?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: There's no "Oracle client database". Are you perhaps thinking of the database client (completely different thing)?

Comment: I've seen a page talking about "Difference Between Oracle Client And Oracle Server"
in this link http://scn.sap.com/thread/350693
So I got confused

Comment: So that "database client" is it a normal db on a client machine or what??

Comment: That thread explains what the difference is, why are you asking again here?

Comment: They are talking about for what we use client and server.. I want to know is it an option during the installation process or a stand alone package or what?

Comment: Post your requirements explicitly in Stack Overflow. Don't assume or expect others to see the URL posted and understand on your behalf. `Server` and `Desktop` class installation is different, and the `Oracle installer` prompts you to choose between the options.

Answer (score 0):

It is your environment, your requirement, your decision, whether to install Oracle as :

1. Server class
2. Desktop class

Choose from the options accordingly.

I think, you must also read about client-server model for a better understanding. I don't have to look at the URL posted by you, all I care is what you describe here in Stack Overflow. Anyway, my suggestions will be seen as comments and not a part of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probabely the original question is a bit ill formed, but I'm interpreting the question to be in concern of the choise of the *systemclass*

When installing Oracle Database recently I was asked to choose the systemclass. I had toh decide whether to install Oracle as :

1. Server class
2. Desktop class

I didn't have further information about the differences of the two possible system classes. As my installation is for Dev-Usage on a desktop computer, I supposed Oracle would use this information for resource configuration and decided for (2) Desktop class.

**Result**
I wasn't able to connect from a client computer to the DB, even though the listener was up, running and correctly configured by listener.ora. After endless and desperate research and even a lot more of trial/error measures, I completely uninstalled the DB. After reinstallation with Systemclass=Serverclass the remote access was fine then, immediately.

It's a pity but I didn't find more information about the meaning of Systemclass. Looking back, the option to setup with systemclass=Desktop class seems a bit pointless to me. Even more as I think there is no way to change this once installation is completed.